# solve a flickering issue in a device for some users

Tags: flutter, flicker, trouble-tickets

flickering image white line

[image]

I am trying to fix my app issue which is made of  Flutter and Golang. Some clients facing a flickering issue and only have a flickering with only my app.

How to create an environment for solving that flickering issue? only few users are facing it. i checked on a virtual emulator device from android studio. there app working fine. how to produce a environment to understand and solve a problem?

Comment: Have you made any analysis on what could be the common thing for those users? Same device? Same OS versions? I don't know how anyone here could give you advice on how to replicate an issue that you say only happens for a small amount of users.

Comment: Yes, all three are different devices from different companies 1) Galaxy Z Flip 4
2) OnePlus 10R 5G 
Processor - mediates
Android 13 Dimensity 8100- Max
Ram 8.00 gb+ 6.00 gb
3) Google pixel 6
Android 13. It's 3 device totally were issue occurred.
 I checked even on the emulator. by creating new device with device configuration  but in the emulator it's working properly All three are Android 13,  but I checked many real devices of Android 13  there working fine . I struggling from last one week to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This Happen due to Android Version(Image File) using in your emulator device, delete it and download it again. Or Use the Upgraded version of Android Like Android 12. Because it's happening to most of the user who updated their emulator version from SDK Manager. I'm one of them too. I'm using Android 11 after Update I face this issue then after too much research I delete it and download the new Upgraded Version Android 12 on my emulator device and also downloading the requirement components from the SDK manager. Try it!!!

Comment: I did it.all three devices are  Android 13 but it's not happening in all Android 13 other apps in the user device  working fine but have issues with only my one. I tested on an android emulator and samsung device on Samsung real devices on Samsung. It works fine there but in client devices it's flickering.

Comment: May be you need to update your SDK Tools from SDK Manager in Android Studio or use the alternate Android Emulator like BlueStack or something else. Because there are some bugs in Android Studio SDKs after new updates.